# Near duplicate video detection?

Tags: python, video, hash

Hi I was wondering if there is hash or something to detect near duplicate videos. All I care to get around is compression. is there something similar to [dhash](https://github.com/Jetsetter/dhash) for videos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a video is just a wrapper around a series of images, I would use something like [pyav](http://mikeboers.github.io/PyAV/) to break the video out into images and then process them with `dhash`. It looks like you don't need to save the images to disk, and it is written in `cython` (and is consequently rumored to be pretty fast.) Alternately you could use `opencv` to do something similar, but it I believe the install is more involved.

Here is the ref code for `pyav`

```
import av

container = av.open(path_to_video)

for frame in container.decode(video=0):
    frame.to_image().save('frame-%04d.jpg' % frame.index)
```

It should be pretty simple to stick the `dhash` call in the for loop and kill the `save` part.